# Function to create LineString from Points using Shapely

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapely

I have a list of points:

```
points = [Point(2.2, 4.2), Point(7.2, -25.1), Point(9.26, -2.456)]
```

I am trying to write a function that will  check that this list contains point objects and return then a LineString, so far:

```
def createLineGeom(giveLine):
if type(giveLine) is shapely.geometry.point.Point:
    return LineString(giveLine)
else:
    return 'pointList must contain shapely point object(s)'
```

I am only able to return the else message from createLineGeom(points). Not sure if my problem is with the type() function or my first return statement, I am very much a beginner writing functions.

Thanks!

Update after J_H answer

```
vertices = [Point(2.2, 4.2), Point(7.2, -25.1), Point(9.26, -2.456)]
# function
def createLineGeom(giveLine):
    if isinstance(giveLine, Point):
       return LineString(giveLine)
```

Still returns no value from

```
pls_work = createLineGeom(vertices)
```

Comment: You can create `LineString` from `Point` array, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95670/how-to-create-a-shapely-linestring-from-two-points

Comment: Yes, but first I must check to see if the list contains Point data types which is where I am failing.

My exercise instructions:

" "Create a function called createLineGeom() that takes a list of Shapely Point objects as parameter and returns a LineString object of those input points. Function should first check that the input list really contains Shapely Point(s). Demonstrate the usage of the function by creating LineString -objects with the function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `print(type(giveLine))` to learn the type of the object.

You probably want to use [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) when deciding if it's a Point. Better yet, plunge ahead and try to use the argument. If it's not of a suitable type you will get a helpful stacktrace explaining the trouble.

Comment: The original instructions for this exercise are confusing me:

"Create a function called createLineGeom() that takes a list of Shapely Point objects as parameter and returns a LineString object of those input points. Function should first check that the input list really contains Shapely Point(s). Demonstrate the usage of the function by creating LineString -objects with the function."

So how do I check if the list actually contains shapely point objects? I added an edit above!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @J_H for pointing me in the right direction with isinstance(). I am not sure if my solution is the most efficient option, but it works!

```
def createLineGeom(inList):
    if all(isinstance(x, Point) for x in inList) is True:
        return LineString(inList)
    else:
        return 'pointList must contain shapely point object(s)'
```

---

**edit:** fixed the indentation

Comment: Rather than `inList`, a typical name would be `points`. If you feel it's necessary to document the iterable is a list then add a type annotation to the signature. Also, you said `if expression is True:`, which is too verbose to be pythonic. Please just say `if expression:`